# Unreal engine 5 error "class AActor has no member SetupPlayerComponent"

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

So I'm having an error with my unreal c++ with this function (using ue5)

```
void ARollablePlayer::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent();

}
```

and the error says "class AActor has no member SetupPlayerComponent" on this line
`Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent();`
I put all my code including my header file

```
#include "RollablePlayer.h"

// Sets default values
ARollablePlayer::ARollablePlayer()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ARollablePlayer::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void ARollablePlayer::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent();

}

void ARollablePlayer::MoveRight(float Value) 
{

}

void ARollablePlayer::MoveForward(float Value) 
{

}

void ARollablePlayer::Jump() 
{

}
```

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "RollablePlayer.generated.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"

class UCameraComponent;
class USpringArmComponent;

UCLASS()
class ROLLABLE_API ARollablePlayer : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    ARollablePlayer();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;


    // Define Components
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Components")
        UStaticMeshComponent* Mesh;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Components")
        USpringArmComponent* SpringArm;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Components")
        UCameraComponent* Camera;


    // Variables //
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        float MoveForce = 500.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        float JumpImpulse = 500.0f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        int32 MaxJumpCount = 1;

public: 

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

private:
    // Functions //
    void MoveRight(float Value);
    void MoveForward(float Value);
    void Jump();

    int32 JumpCount = 0;
};
```

Comment: `Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent();` -> `Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);` the base function needs to receive the input argument as well

Comment: the code was randomly generated by ue5(pawn class) so idk what to do

Comment: i did that but gave me an error anyway @UnholySheep

Comment: You can try to explicitly call `APawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent` - although I'm not sure why the `Super` typedef would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to close UE5 editor if you are compiling c++ for the first time.

Answer (score -1):

In your header file "*.generated.h" should always be the last include.

Comment: i did that but got some other weird build error

Comment: 1. I can't just guess what that error is.
2. Have you fixed what UnholySheep pointed in first comment?
3. Are you looking at error list or output?